# the use of ... element in jsx file

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am a beginner at React learning it from an online tutorial.
there is an element used in one of the courses which is `...` and can be seen in the following code

```
handleIncrement = (productId)=>{
        const newProducts=[...this.state.products]
        const index= newProducts.findIndex(p=> p.id === productId)
        newProducts[index].count +=1 ;
        this.setState({products : newProducts});
    }
```

its usage seems to be creating an array from `products` and passing it to the `newProducts` which is an array now. could you please explain what exactly do ... and when we need it to use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's called the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).

In react, you're not supposed to mutate the state directly. So, if you have an array you want to edit, you will first create a copy of the array with the spread syntax, edit the new array, and finally set the state to the edited copy of the array.

Creating a copy with `newProducts = this.state.products` is not sufficient in this case as both the variables are pointing to the same object in memory and changing `newProducts` is the same as changing `this.state.products.